# How do I convert list of strings to list of doubles in closure?

Tags: clojure

How can I convert the values of 'mymap' to a list of Doubles instead of a list of Strings, at the same time as mymap is created?

```
(use '[clojure.string :only (join split)])
;(def raw-data (slurp "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=INTC"))
;Downloaded and removed the first line
(def raw-data (slurp "table-INTC.csv"))


(def raw-vector-list
  (map
    #(split % #",")          ; anonymous map function to split by comma
    (split raw-data #"\n"))) ; split raw data by new line

(pr (take 1 raw-vector-list))

(def mymap 
  (zipmap 

    ;construct composite key out of symbol and date which is head of the list
    (map #(str "INTC-" %) (map first raw-vector-list))

    ;How do i convert these values to Double instead of Strings?
    (map rest raw-vector-list)))

(pr (take 1 mymap))
```

Comment: Clojure's csv package would save you a fair bit of code here. https://github.com/davidsantiago/clojure-csv

Comment: Once I get a good grasp on what the heck i'm doing at a basic level, i'll explore that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(def mymap
  (zipmap 
    (map #(str "NAT-" %) (map first raw-vector-list)) 
    (map #(map (fn [v] (Double/parseDouble v)) %)
         (map rest raw-vector-list))))

(pprint (take 1 mymap))
-> (["NAT-1991-09-30" (41.75 42.25 41.25 42.25 3.62112E7 1.03)])
```

Another version

```
(def mymap
  (map (fn [[date & values]]
         [(str "NAT-" date)
          (map #(Double/parseDouble %) values)])
       ;; Drop first non-parsable element in raw-vector-list
       ;; ["Date" "Open" "High" "Low" "Close" "Volume" "Adj Close"]
       (drop 1 raw-vector-list)))
```

Comment: How did you even fathom that? Can you pull out the magic part into a separate defn for further investigation?

Comment: It's not the magic. Just don't forget that "(map rest raw-vector-list)" returns sequence of sequences. That's why you need outer "map" that applies inner "map" to every subsequences.

Comment: I did not have a complete picture of the data structure. I was conceptualizing what I can only describe as a Composite when what was required was that it was actually a list of lists. Thank you very much.

Comment: Oh and your second version, is quite eye opening. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

So for the tail/rest portion of this data. You are mapping an anonymous, map function, to a list of strings, and then mapping the type conversion to the elements in each sublist.

```
(def mymap
  (zipmap 
   (map #(str "NAT-" %) (map first raw-vector-list)) 
   (map #(map (fn [v] (Double/parseDouble v)) %)
     (map rest raw-vector-list))))
```

How can I pull out the type conversion into a function like below...And then utilize my custom method?

```
(defn str-to-dbl [n] (Double/parseDouble n))
```

This code complains about nested #'s.

```
(def mymap
  (zipmap 
   (map #(str "NAT-" %) (map first raw-vector-list)) 
   (map #(map #(str-to-double %)
     (map rest raw-vector-list))))
```